# installing Google Cloud SDK on Compute Engine: permission denied error

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, sdk, google-compute-engine

I started an instance on Google Compute Engine based on cos-stable image (for Docker). Now I try to install cloud SDK on my VM (unfortunately I did not find any image with Docker AND gcloud). Following instructions from Google doc (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart) I did:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-313.0.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xvf google-cloud-sdk-313.0.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
```

but got the error `-bash: ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: Permission denied`. Same result with sudo. What did I do wrong?

Comment: COS is locked down. You'll be unable to install software packages directly on an instance. https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits Review the CoreOS toolbox: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The COS is minimal to run docker and.... that's all!! I won't be surprised is many stuff are forbidden to keep the VM attack surface the smallest possible.

I recommend you to use this command instead:

```
docker run -it google/cloud-sdk:slim
```

With a `gcloud auth list` you can see that the Compute Engine service account is detected and you can use it to perform your actions.

*Enter `exit` or perform Ctrl+D to exit the container in interactive mode*

Comment: Thanks for the answer Guillaume. I'm not sure I understand the rationale though as I can install Docker by myself on a VM. What's the difference in terms of VM vulnerability from attack?

Comment: The name is "attack surface". Fewer you have stuff installed on your server, higher is your security. When an app is installed, there is dependencies, possibly deprecated, with know CVE or issues. to decrease the risk, decrease the number of installed app. And COS is minimal and design to only run container